# Two Separate QGIS Plugins Under one Provider

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have developed a QGIS processing plugin that has a processing provider of its own. That plugin is working fine. Now I am developing a second plugin and I want to provide it the same provider so that I can have something like this where many algorithms are under Vector Selection Provider:

[image]

These two plugins are different and hence I don't want to package them under same plugin but do wants them to have same provider.

So far I have tried giving the second Plugin Provider the same name as first one but I am getting this error:

Error while unloading plugin curve_number_generator

```
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type CurveNumberGeneratorProvider has been deleted 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 434, in unloadPlugin
    plugins[packageName].unload()
  File "C:/Users/abdul/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\curve_number_generator\curve_number_generator.py", line 74, in unload
    QgsApplication.processingRegistry().removeProvider(self.provider)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type CurveNumberGeneratorProvider has been deleted
```

Comment: I do want seperate plugins because I want to give user the chance to download either just one or both plugins ... If I store them all together then it will be just one plugin on QGIS repository

Comment: @user2856 Thanks. Is that then possible to just not have anything display in the processing panel for a processing plugin and create a custom menu group in the menu toolbar for all my plugins, under which all the separate plugins are listed? I can live without any button in the processing panel since there will already be buttons in the menu toolbar group.

Comment: The reason why I don't want to have them display as separate providers in the processing panel is that I plan to develop more plugins and they all will be taking up their own space cluttering the panel.